# Changing the selected text of a select box in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, coffeescript

I have a function where if the user changes an IP to be unallocated in the select box, an alert will pop-up that asks if they are sure, on cancelling this alert I want the select2 box to change back to the original status (i.e allocated etc.).

I have been able to change the value of the select2 box by storing the original value in a variable and then assigning it to the value of the select on cancelling the alert

```
else
    $('#ip_status').val(original_status)
```

However although this DOES change the value of the select2 box meaning the functionality is working, the text in the select2 box stays 'unallocated' giving the end user a misleading value. Keep in mind that .text(" example ") does not work.

Thank you.

Full Code -

```
original_status = document.getElementById('ip_status').value
$('#ip_status').change ->

# If the user changes ip status to unallocated, clear and hide system name and description fields.
if parseInt($('#ip_status').val()) == 0

  r = confirm("You are about to unallocate this IP! Are you sure you want to do this?")
  if r == true
    $('#ip_description').val("").parent().hide()
    $('#ip_system_name').val("").parent().hide()

  else
    $('#ip_status').val(original_status)
else
  # if the select changes to allocated or reserved, re-show the fields that were hidden
  $('#ip_description').parent().show()
  $('#ip_system_name').parent().show()
```

Comment: can you provide the existing code you are using

Comment: How is your question related to Coffeescript? All I see is JQuery.

Comment: @AlexisDufrenoy Isn't `$('#ip_status').change ->` coffeescript? the `->` part. `->` means function I believe.

Comment: Yes this is all coffeescript, you are able to reference dom elements through '$' in this file. 'ips.js.coffee'. I have also posted an answer to my own question as I found it within some documentation.

Comment: @JackO'Connor `$` is jQuery.

Comment: The file contains both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by changing

```
$('#ip_status').val(original_status)
```

to

```
$("#ip_status").select2("val", original_status)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use something like:

```
$( function() {
    $("#your_option").attr("selected", "selected");
});
```